# cookie value back into input fields

Tags: php, forms, cookies

i'm actually new to PHP so i need your help!

I'm using a table within a form, and SQL Server to fill the table rows.
The form starts with an input field for quantity input type="number".

```
<form name="testform" method="post" action="submit.php">

<?php

$sql="query goes here";
$query=sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));

        if ($query) {

            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                     echo "<td><input type='number' name='quantity[]'></td>";
       }
    }
?>
</form>
```

After submitting the form, i want the user to have the possibility to navigate back to the previous page to change the quantity input if possible. 
So i need to restore the input values when navigating back (all values are now lost when navigating back).

I found this way by using the Cookies to store the input values so i found a way to store all values of input name='quantity[]' (array) in the cookies. And print them on the page when navigating back. It prints all values correct with the correct array index position as well. 
Here's some of the code:

On my form page (form.php) for receiving cookies.

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE['Cookie_Info'])){

    $cookie = $_COOKIE["Cookie_Info"]; 
    $cookie = stripslashes($cookie); 
    $savedAantArray = json_decode($cookie, true); 

    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($savedAantArray); echo '</pre>';


    } else { 

    $data = array(
        'quantity[]' => ''       
    );
   }

?>
```

On my submit page (submit.php) for setting cookies, with link to return to form.php page.

```
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $post_arr = $_POST;
            $expire = 8*3600; 
            setcookie("Cookie_Info", serialize($post_arr), time()+$expire); 
        }
    ?>
<a href="form.php">Make Some Changes..</a>
```

Result when returning to form.php

```
Cookies
Array
(
    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 8
        )

    [submit] => Submit
)
```

Here's my question:
Is there a way to store those values from the array into all the right input fields?
Instead of printing them just as an array (which is not what i want, but i wanted to test the cookie storage).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use $_SESSION to remember the values across pages, create a subarray in  $_SESSION global variable

Comment: Do you store the value in DB after submitting the form for the first time?

Comment: Hi Harry, no not yet. The submit is just a layer between form.php and the actual insert.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Yvon, got it working now.

Again on my second page:

```
<?php session_start();

        $_SESSION['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];

        foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $value) {

        echo "<input name='quantity' value='$value'>\n<br />";
     }

 ?>
```

Back to first page:

```
<?php session_start();

    $quantity=$_SESSION['quantity'];
    print_r($quantity);
    echo "<br \>";

        foreach($_SESSION['quantity'] as $key => $value) {

        echo "<input name='quantity[]' value='$value'>\n<br />";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small edit, got it working perfect now (including printing the correct amount of rows).

On the first page:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="second.php">

<?php session_start();

include 'db_connect.php';

$quantity=$_SESSION['quantity']; print_r($quantity); echo "<br \>";

$sql ="SELECT * FROM X0ONTDTA.WEBRELGB";
$query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));


    if($query){

            if (isset($_SESSION['quantity'])){

                    foreach($_SESSION['quantity'] as $key => $value) {

                echo "<input  name='quantity[]' value='$value'>\n<br />";
            }
        } 

        elseif($query){

            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

                echo "<input name='quantity[]' value=''>\n<br />";

            }


            }
        }

?>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></input>

</form>
```

On the second page:

```
<?php session_start();

$_SESSION['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];

   foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $value) {

       echo "<input name='quantity' value='$value'>\n<br />";
    }

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_POST['quantity']);
  echo "</pre>";

?>

<a href="first.php"> Go Back </a>
```

Resulting in this:

[after submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUEel.png)

[going back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iUkl.png)